# Подскажите какой нибудь материал (желательно на русском) по изучению github?

Tags: github

Подскажите какой нибудь материал (желательно на русском) по изучению github?

Comment: С Git работаете нормально?

Comment: Нет. Без понятия, я даже не знаю чем они отличаются

Comment: Google еще работает... https://githowto.com/ru

Comment: @Vlad Spirin, сам в шоке)

Answer (score 3):

Могу посоветовать [русский перевод](https://habrahabr.ru/post/150673/) книги "Pro Git".

> «Pro Git» — это довольно обширная обучающая книга о Git от Скотта Шакона — активного участника разработки проектов Git и GitHub. Автор рассматривает в тексте всевозможные аспекты работы с Git'ом...

Answer (score 2):

Так как по вашим словам вы не разбираетесь в Git, для начала поймите, что к чему.
[Вам в этом поможет такая программа](https://learngitbranching.js.org).
Выберете там необходимый язык (бывает такое, что по дефорту он запускает английский, запустите что-либо, чтоб открылось окно и был доступ к кнопке с глобусиком и выберете там соответствующий язык, далее вернитесь к самому началу, уже на нужном языке). Мне в свое время очень помогла эта программа, да и ее в некоторых серьезных компаниях, как раз таки дают новичкам чтоб разобрались с Git.

#### Литература

[Pro Git book на русском онлайн](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2)

*Как только вы все пройдете и поймете, я вам в этот ответ добавлю информацию по GitHub.* Отпишитесь в комментариях я увижу.

Comment: Минус то за что поставили? Информация адекватная, помогает новичку разобраться в вопросе... Автор минуса, отзовитесь пожалуйста, хочу знать что не так и как могу исправить или дополнить данный вопрос.