# Команды Git куда писать

Tags: git

Подскажите, пожалуйста, чайнику в Git.
Куда писать вот это:

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"  
git config --global user.email "your_email@whatever.com"
```

у меня Windows 7

Comment: @slo_nik ["Пожалуйста, не отправляйте задающих вопросы в поисковики"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2013/181100)

Comment: писать в терминал, я [тут отвечал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/777446/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b4%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e-github/777451#777451), воспользуйтесь данным приложением для разбора Git

Comment: Как запускаете гит?

Comment: По этой же ссылке онлайн учебник по гит на русском

Answer (score 1):

Комбинация клавиш `win` + `r`, далее пишите `cmd`, откроется консоль, там нужно писать команды.

Comment: просто в командной строке? А не надо в какую-либо папку переходить перед тем, как вводить эти команды?

Comment: @Ирина, когда редактируете файл конфига, то можно не переходить.

Comment: пока ничего не редактирую - тупо следую по шагам этого учебника: https://githowto.com/ru/setup

Comment: @Ирина, тогда не важно в какой директории.

Comment: Вообще-то важно.

Comment: @Qwertiy на той конкретной странице изменяются **глобальные** настройки. Для них -- неважно.

Comment: @D-side, хм.. Да, согласен.